# Login PHP does not work properly

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, session, login-script

I am using an AJAX HTTP request to pass login data to my php login script. When the data is passed, the php script returns that the username and password variables are empty after they are checked in the error handling. I am using valid login details from my database. The password has been hashed when the user signs up using the password_hash(); method so maybe this is the problem?

This is the login PHP script:

```
   <?php
     session_start();

     if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
        //Establish DB Connection
        include_once 'DBConnection.php';
        //Store Username and Password from Login Form
        $Username = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST[ 'Username' ] );
        $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST[ 'Password' ] );

       //Error Handlers
      //Check if inputs are empty
      if ( empty( $Username ) || empty( $Password ) ) {
        header( "Location: ../index.php?login=empty" );
        exit();
       } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username='" . $Username . "'";
            $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows( $result );
            if ( $resultCheck < 1 ) {
                header( "Location: ../index.php?login=error" );
                exit();
             } else {
                if ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
                    //Dehash Password
                    $hashedPasswordCheck = password_verify( $Password, $row[ 'Password' ] );
                  if ( $hashedPasswordCheck == false ) {
                     header( "Location: ../index.php?login=error" );
                     exit();
                  } elseif ( $hashedPasswordCheck == true ) {
                    //Log in user
                    $_SESSION[ 'u_id' ] = $row[ 'User_ID' ];
                    $_SESSION[ 'u_first' ] = $row[ 'Forename' ];
                    $_SESSION[ 'u_last' ] = $row[ 'Surname' ];
                    $_SESSION[ 'u_email' ] = $row[ 'Email' ];
                    $_SESSION[ 'u_user' ] = $row[ 'Username' ];
                    header( "Location: ../index.php?login=success" );
                    exit();
                }
             }
          }
        }
    } else {
      header( "Location: ../index.php?login=error" );
      exit();
 }
```

This is the form code:

```
   <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="../Assets/SignIn.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email Address</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Username" placeholder="Email Address/Username" required>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
     <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="ajax_Login()">Sign in</button>
   </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the AJAX Request:

```
    function ajax_Login(){
      "use strict";
      //Create XMLHttpRequest object
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     //Create variables to store data to be sent to PHP file
     var url = "signIn.php";
     var uname = document.getElementById("Username").value;
     var pword = document.getElementById("Password").value;
     var vars = "Username="+uname+"&Password="+pword;
     request.open("POST", url, true);
     //Set content type header info for sending url encoded variables in the request
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //Access the onreadystatechange event for XMLHttpRequest object
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
        var return_data = request.responseText;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
      }
   };
  //Send data to PHP file
  request.send(vars);
```

}

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: @Phil what's the error you are getting?

Comment: can you type the error message please

Comment: header( "Location: ../index.php?login=error" );
      exit();

Comment: this is the code from the last else statement in the script, this contains the error I am getting

Answer (score -1):

Please check your submit button name because submit is not set that's why you got an error

Comment: Thank you, I specified the button name and it is now giving me this error message: header( "Location: ../index.php?login=empty" );
        exit();

Comment: Button name can not solve your problem, because HTML form does not catch button elements as its $_POST values.

Answer (score -1):

When you submit a POST method form, it send a POST request to server, then the global `$_POST` is set.

Let take a look in your code:
You used `isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] )` to check if login form is submitted. It means that you have to have a HTML form element (input, checkbox, etc) with `submit` name. If you do not, just simple check `isset($_POST)` to query db or continue working.

```
<?php
     if ( isset( $_POST ) ) {
        session_start();
        //Establish DB Connection
        include_once 'DBConnection.php';
...
```

Hope this help

Comment: This also works, however, my script is now returning this error message: header( "Location: ../index.php?login=empty" );
        exit();
This is inside the statement that checks if the form is empty. The form is not empty and I have used correct login details

Comment: Are you referring to the input types being email and password rather than simply input?